# Rig only generating root but I can't use Human(metarig)

Tags: rigging

So I'm trying to rig a character but I don't want to use the Human meta rig because my character is similar to a early n64 character because it doesn't have fingers. I've heard people say on similar threads to just rename all the bones to match the ones on the human metarig but my character dosn't have all the bones the metarig does(I have tried renaming what I have). I tried getting the human meta rig and then deleting all the bones[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHg1f.jpg) I don't need but that just ends in a error,any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Simple Human metarig, which has no fingers and no facial bones, edit it accordingly to your character, then generate the Rigify rig, which has complex and sophisticated mechanisms that lets you animate easier.

For further infos relate to Blender manual:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html

Comment: thanks but is there a way to delete the shoulder bones and pelvis and combine all the neck bones into one without a generating error

Comment: No. You have to build your own rig, instead. If you want you can use some pieces of Rigify only (like arms, or legs, or spine), but you can't break none of them. Anyway you can generate the complete rig, and then use only the parts you need, hiding or deleting the unnecessary bones (after generating the final rig).